# Facebook Api новая строка в посте

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

Здравствуйте, добавляю новый пост с картинкой на страницу в фейсбуке

```
$fb->post("/{$group_id}/photos", array(
    'message' => 'This is a \\u000A test message \\n #aaa #bbb',
    'url' => 'http://lurkmore.so/images/3/31/Yoba_Best_01.jpg',
), $token);
```

Но никак не могу заставить писать с новой строки, пробовал `<br/>`, `\n`, `<center></center> \n`. Подскажите, как можно сделать? Нужно писать хэштеги, не красиво когда они не с новой строки.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй приконкатировать вот такую часть строки `"\r\n"`, обязательно в двойных кавычках, должно сработать.

Comment: Все равно данный текст просто выводится в тех двойных кавычках и все.

Answer (score 0):

Если постит на стену - может банально `<br/>` попробовать?.... \r\n Переводит на новую стоку для заголовков вроде как...

Comment: <br/> тоже пробовал, не работает, просто выводится.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, нужно было тест выводить в двойных кавычках, тогда \r\n приводит к переносу строки

Comment: или же сделать вот так `"test". "\r\n"`, что я изначально имел ввиду